# How to print function argument name that was used to call this function in F#

Tags: f#

How can I print argument function name that was used to call this function?

```ml
open System
open System.Threading.Tasks

let logger (f: ('a -> Task<'b>)) : ('a -> Task<'b>) =
    printfn "Hey: %O" (nameof f) // I would like to print "myFunc", not "f"
    f

let myFunc x = task {return x }

let d = (logger myFunc) 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `ReflectedDefinition(true)` attribute, which automatically quotes the argument of a method call and gives you both the value (to use at runtime) and the code quotation from which you can (if the format is right) extract the name. This only seems to work with method calls though:

```
type Logger = 
  static member log([<ReflectedDefinition(true)>]f: Expr<('a -> Task<'b>)>) : ('a -> Task<'b>) =
    match f with 
    | Patterns.WithValue(v, _, Patterns.Lambda(_, Patterns.Call(_, mi, _))) ->
        printfn "Hello %s!" mi.Name
        unbox v
    | _ -> failwith "Wrong format"

let myFunc x = task {return x }

let d = (Logger.log myFunc) 3
```

The design and motivation of this is discussed in the [F# 4.0 Speclet: Auto-Quotation of Arguments at Method Calls](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/main/FSharp-4.0/AutoQuotationDesignAndSpec.md)

Comment: Thanks Tomas, do you know if there is a significant hit to the performance? I mean in logging it doesn't matter so much, but there are more this kind of aspects too like using this in e.g. memoization.

Comment: @TuomasHietanen I'm not sure - I have not tested this. I would expect that there is some overhead (the compiler has to generate the quotation data structure with the information when calling the method, which is not super huge, but it is a couple of allocations) - but it should not be anything insane (we are not doing any reflection to extract the value - that is stored directly in the data structure)...